# Get layer of shape in Visio in Python

Tags: python, visio

I'm trying to select all shapes within an existing Visio-file that are i. e. in layer "help" to delete them. Is there a way to achive that using python package "vsdx"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CreateSelection method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.page.createselection) with parameter `visSelTypeByLayer = 3`.

Right now I haven't Python environment there, my simple VBA code

```
Sub SOF_77409035()
Dim Sh As Shape
Dim sl As Selection
ActiveWindow.DeselectAll ' deselect all   
Set sl = ActivePage.CreateSelection(3, 0, "help") ' create selection in memory    
For Each Sh In sl ' iterate all shapes in selection    
'    ActiveWindow.Select Sh, 2 ' select shape visSelect = 2    
     sh.delete    
Next    
End Sub
```

---

**UPDATE**
This python-code can print a list of shapes belonging to a layer.
But it cannot select these shapes.

```
import win32com.client as w32 
visio = w32.Dispatch("visio.Application") 
visio.Visible = 1 
win = visio.activewindow
doc = visio.activedocument
pag = doc.pages(1)
sl = pag.createselection(3, 0,"help")
for i in range (1, sl.count+1):
    sh = sl.item(i)
    sh.delete
```

**PS** [vsdx python package](https://pypi.org/project/vsdx/) have [poor documentation](https://vsdx.readthedocs.io), I suspect that's not possible.

Comment: For the task to delete the shapes thats working.
If someone wants to go further one can get the id of the issued items by editing the code above '''sh.delete''' to '''sh.id'''. Export these ids to a list i. e. and now '''find_shape_by_id''' from vsdx package is your friend.